# Passing variable to function in javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

quick question,why this don`t work and how to fix it

```
$("#Button").click(function(){
        count++;
    var b=new Button(count);
    b.render();
 $("#div"+ count).dblclick(function(){
  var diva=this;
   $(this).append("<span id='colorchange'><input type='color' id='color' onchange='func("+diva+")' name='favcolor'></span>");

});

});

function func(diva){
 alert(diva);
 }
```

i`m getting error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Does the error say anything else about the Unexpected identifier?

Comment: You should bind event handlers as functions, not attribute strings

Comment: I don't think "var diva=this;" is doing what you think it is doing.  You are trying to stuff that into the onchange event of an element, but that is a reference to an object.  Not 100% sure what you are trying to do with that onchange event.  Do you want to alert the ID of the element?

Comment: boy javascript is a mess,i`m trying to pass the id of the div to a function ,how can i do it ?

Comment: Anything is a mess if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: There's no syntax error in this code. Which line does the error say it's on and what else does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

You can add jquery library "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js",
and Button is not recognized unless you defined it anywhere...
You can get help from "http://sideroad.secret.jp/plugins/jQueryRender/"